# How to validate the Article - Intro Image field in the backend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-content, validations

When managing an Article in the administrator/backend, it is possible to insert a non-url into the "Intro Image" field (located in the "Images and Links" tab).

[image]

Upon clicking "Select" a modal window containing a text input field labeled "Image URL" (among other options) appears.  This field expects a url string like `images/abc.jpg`, but there is no validation on the text in the field so a non-url value can be submitted.  I want to eliminate the possibility of a non-url value like html, javascript, etc. from being stored.  e.g. `<img src="xxx/yy/zbx.jpg" onmouseover="alert(xxxx)" />`

[image]

Ideally, I wish to deny the submission from the modal, so that the parent form can not receive the non-url value and generate the following:

[image]

Ultimately I'd like to validate the url field when saving the Article.

Comment: @mickmackusa: When there is an unclear or other problematic question, use the available tools to mark it - e.g send it to the review queue - so more users will review it. During the review period the OP might edit his question. If not it will be in track for the community to moderate it, otherwise it can stay forgotten.

Comment: @mohan - Your question is on hold as unclear. Feel free to edit and clarify as best as you can what your question is about.

Comment: @FFrewin I think I understand the question now and can replicate the issue. I've performed a heavy-handed edit and voted to Reopen.

Comment: @mohan let's move this question forward.  Did one of the answers solve your issue? If so, please award the green tick.  If not, please state what is left to fix.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent invalid values from being passed to the parent window, you can create an override of mediafield.js (and minified mediafield.min.js) which is located in /media/media/js/ folder.

Add your filtering/validation here:

```
        // bind insert
        content.on('click', self.options.buttonSaveSelected, function(){
            var value = content.find('#f_url').val();
            if (value) {
                self.setValue(value);
            }
            self.modalClose.call(self);
        });
```

This snippet should strip out HTML from value ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript#822486)).

```
            var tmp = document.createElement("div");
            tmp.innerHTML = value;
            value = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
```

To prevent invalid values from being saved to database, no action should be needed as by default HTML is filtered out from the field. But if you want to change the filter, create a content plugin with `onContentPrepareForm` event and set the filter of the field there:

```
public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data)
{
    if ($form->getName() !== 'com_content.article')
    {
        return true;
    }

    $form->setFieldAttribute('image_intro', 'filter', 'SOMEFILTER', 'images');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an override of `administrator > components > com_content > models > article.php`

Inside that override, find this function (line 549 in article.php):

```
if (isset($data['images']) && is_array($data['images']))
{
    $registry = new Registry($data['images']);

    $data['images'] = (string) $registry;
}
```

Add this before `$registry` inside the function:

```
$imgToCheck = $data['images']['image_intro'];
$application = JFactory::getApplication();
if (preg_match('~^[a-z0-9/.-]+$~i', $imgToCheck)) {
    // This is a URL
    $application->enqueueMessage('URL OK');
} else {
    // Not an valid URL
    $application->enqueueMessage(JText::_('Please use a valid URL'), 'Invalid URL');
    exit();
}
```

This will test the url input for the intro image.

I'm not really good at `preg_match`, but this should only allow letters from A-Z and numbers and `/`and `.`...You can change this to match your needs.

I hope this will help you! I'm not really expierenced in Joomla myself, but since no one answered this question, I though I would do my best to help.

Comment: how to add this validation in joomla....?

Comment: @mohan see updated answer

Comment: thanks. but noting is working. no affect of validation after insert.

Comment: What if you replace `$application->enqueueMessage('URL OK');` with `die("URL OK");` and `$application->enqueueMessage(JText::_('Please use a valid URL'), 'Invalid URL');` with `die("not ok");` ?

Comment: If nothing comes up, then your override may not work. Or you are not using the "intro image" field

Comment: I've corrected the syntax of your regex pattern to eliminate unnecessary escaping, but -- honestly -- that pattern doesn't resemble a URL validator.

Comment: sorry for not reply . problem solved byadding css code in administrator/template/iris/css/template.css. code: #jform_images_image_intro{
  pointer-events:none;
 }
#jform_images_image_fulltext
{
 pointer-events:none;
 }